# Next/image blocking for navbar

Tags: next.js, navbar, tailwind-css, next-images

I'm using next/image as a header image, but when i use my navbars dropdown menu, the image is in front of the dropdown. How do i fix this, while still using next/image? :-)

Github: https://github.com/Lucashunt/jameshunt

website: https://jameshunt.vercel.app

[Displaying correct over text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OCdna.png)

[Image in front of dropdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gVCzf.jpg)

Comment: Add code to your question for a better answer

Comment: While providing a link to the code is fine, your question should be self-contained and preferably not rely on external resources to be answered. Please add the relevant code to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you set position:relative if you are using layout:fill. Also visit the [doc](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/image) to understand the required props.

Comment: See my update, still doesn't work any clue?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hzahe.png

Comment: Add a code snippet, so we know how to help